# FSCK error in superblock causing Ubuntu Linux 64 bit failed to boot?

Tags: ubuntu, fsck

Today for strange reason, one of my Ubuntu 64 bit server Linux VM failed to start ?
it stopped in the FSCK scan status with the error as attached.
[image]
[image]

few days back I've added new hard disk successfully and format it as sdb5 without problem.

Any guidance and comments will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

here's the updated[image]
[image]

Comment: Look to me like it might be an error in fstab, could we see your /etc/fstab ?

Comment: thanks for the reply mate, unfortunately I couldn't copy paste the /etc/fstab content here because the boot process was stuck as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first screenshot seems to show a particular problem with fscking the device `/media/extraspace/hudson/.m2/repository`, which is in turn on the device `LABEL=extraspace`.  You could try changing the fsck pass of the former to 0, with the line

```
/media/extraspace/hudson/.m2/repository   /var/lib/hudson/.m2/repository   ext4  bind,defaults   0 0
```

(changing the terminal 2 to a 0) and skip the fsck pass.  That should let you get the system up and running, and hopefully you can then look into why that line's there and whether the device should be fscked at boot or not.

If that does help and you want to fsck at boot, try changing the 2 to a 3: I see that `LABEL=extraspace` is fscked in pass 2 also, and there's no way you can fsck a file system which is inside another file system which is currently being fscked, and is therefore not yet mounted.

Comment: wow, you're right I did change all of those 2 into all 0 since this is just a VM, so in this case for all of my LINUX VM i shall set the FSCK level all to 0 no matter what.